# Java multiple interface with parameter

Tags: java

Suppose i have 2 interface which is

```
interface add{
    
      void add2No(float a, float b);
}
```

and

```
interface Minus{
        
      void Minus2No(float a, float b);
}
```

then on the main method, i already overide the method which is

```
public class Count implements Add, Minus {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    
            //declare var
            float a, b;
            String temp;
    
            //create object
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            Count obj = new Count();
    
            //User Input
            System.out.print("Enter your first Number : ");
            temp = br.readLine();
            a = Float.parseFloat(temp);
    
            System.out.print("Enter your second Number : ");
            temp = br.readLine();
            b = Float.parseFloat(temp);
    
      
    
            System.out.println("Value of " +a+ " + " +b+ " is : " +obj.Totaladd(float a, float b));
            System.out.println("Value of " +a+ " + " +b+ " is : " +obj.TotalMinus(float a, float b));
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void Add2No(float a, float b) {
    
            float TotalAdd = a + b;
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void Minus2No(float a, float b) {
    
            float TotalMinus = a - b;
        }
    }
```

Am i using the correct implementation for interface? why there's error when i try to print out the TotalAdd and TotalMinus?

Comment: It's always a good idea to paste the exact error. This is especially true in the event you have multiple problems with your code,

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Because you don't return the results. Currently both methods are `void`. You **could** change that. Like,

```
interface Add {   
    float add2No(float a, float b);
}

interface Minus {
    float minus2No(float a, float b);
}
```

And then

```
@Override
public float add2No(float a, float b) {
    return a + b;
}

@Override
public float minus2No(float a, float b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three wrong places.

The first wrong place:

> Because Java is case sensitive.
>
> The name of your interface method is called `add2No`, but the name of
> your implementation is called `Add2No`

The second wrong place:

> There is a problem with your method parameter passing and the way of
> calling. I did not see the `Totaladd` and `Totaladd` methods defined in
> your Count object.
>
> If you adjust the case, there should only be `add2No` and `Minus2No`
> methods in Count object.
>
> You need to adjust the name of one of them, and do not pass the type when passing parameters.
>
> For example: `obj.Totaladd(float a, float b)` should be `obj.Totaladd(a, b)`

The third wrong place:

> If you need to call the method to get the value for calculation, you must adjust the type of the method, it should not be `void`